# <Client>.users.cache.size not working with Discord.js bot

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I have a problem with just a bit of my code:

```js
<Client>.users.cache.size
```

It was working perfectly before but one day it begins to give me random numbers instead of the number of users the bot.

So I would like to fix this but I didn't find how.

Comment: Check your Server Member Intent in your Discord Developer Portal. [Learn About Intents Here](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/intents.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, it is working:

```js
<Client>.guilds.cache.reduce((a, b) => a + b.memberCount, 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

As the property implies it only gives you back the count of **users saved in the cache**.
That is what makes the number look *random*.
Ways of getting the actual number of people that have ever used your bot is by either doing it with **Discord Intents** (as Elitezen said in the comment) or - which is also quite common and the way i prefer - you can connect your bot to a **database** and store all of your users there. ([MongoDB](https://www.mongodb.com/) is pretty popular).